# Is it natural to use "cases" in the context?

Tags: word-choice

Woman:  Do you think he'll ever come out of his coma?

Doctor: I don't know. Cases like this are always hard to predict, so I can't say. We can only hope for the best.

Is it natural to use "cases" here or is there a better option?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, **cases** is the appropriate word.

People might also talk about examples, instances or situations but none of these fits as well as **cases**.